# jquery reveal check if checkbox is checked before closing

Tags: jquery, html, reveal.js

I'm working with jquery reveal. This is a piece of my code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
            <p>bmla</p>
        <input id="read" type="checkbox" value="read">I've read it</input>
        <a id="ok" class="close-reveal-modal">OK</a>
    </div>
```

I want to check if my chebock is checked before I close this modal..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            if (/bla/.test(self.location.href)) {
                $('#myModal').reveal({
                    animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
                    animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
                    closeonbackgroundclick: false
                });
            }
        });
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share your reveal modal initialisation jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : bind click event to `'OK'` link and check if checkbox is checked or not to close modal. And set '`dismissmodalclass`' to any other class so that on click of `OK` it will not close modal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('#ok').click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             if($('#read').is(':checked'))
             {
              $('#myModal').trigger('reveal:close');
              return true;
             }
             else
             {
               alert('Please check the checkbox');
               return false;
             }
          });

       if (/bla/.test(self.location.href)) { 
          $('#myModal').reveal({
                    animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
                    animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
                    closeonbackgroundclick: false,
                    dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal1' // class name changed to avoid close of modal on click of OK link
           });
       }
    });
```

Comment: This isn't working. It still closes when the checkbox isn't checked

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle of this so that i can help you better way.